# If you don't care for me, I will hurt you. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

I come after you are born

I'm painful when born

I reveal myself when happiness comes

But if you do not care for me I will hurt you.

Born two times

I live no longer as you live.

I have two families in the same home, we all are fair.

No one gets hurt if one of us dies.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Surely you intend "Came after you were born" or "Comes after you're born" or "Came after your birth" rather than "Came after your born"?? Puzzles often turn on such subtleties, you can't really afford to be careless with "your". There are a few other odd expressions in there but they don't quite have the same capacity to mislead as that one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is

> tooth / teeth

Came after your born

> It will grow in time after baby is born

I'm painful when born

> Babies are irritated when they started to grow because it is painful or itchy that is why they use teething toys

Its comes to show when happiness comes,

> When smiling, it shows

But if you do not care I will hurt you soon

> It will rot and needs to be extracted by a dentist when you do not brush your teeth or take care of it

Born two times

> Milk teeth is first and Permanent teeth is second

I live no longer as you live

> When you die, teeth will no longer have a function but they don't decay

Have two family in same home, we all are fair.

> Upper jaw set and lower jaw set of teeth

No one get hurt if one die.

> Other tooth will still function even one is extracted